# R DataTable Count Unique Observations by Group and Add Column

Tags: r, count, data.table

```
DATA=data.table(STUDENT=c(1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4),       
    CHAR=c("cat","cat","cat","fox","fox","fox","fox","fox","fox","fox","fox"),      
    WANT=c(1,2,2,1,1,6,6,6,6,6,6))
```

I have 'DATA' and wish to generate 'WANT' using data.table where 'WANT' equals to the COUNT of the unique variable in 'CHAR' for each 'STUDENT' so for example STUDENT ==2 has 2 "cat" and 1 "fox" so WANT equals to '2' where STUDENT ==2 and CHAR =="cat" and WANT equals to '1' where STUDENT ==2 and CHAR == "fox"

Comment: @akrun do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice one row solution

```
DATA[,new := .N, by = .(STUDENT,CHAR)][]
```